# Einstein Email Recommendations - historical purchase data

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is it possible to import historical purchase data to Einstein Email Recommendations without using SF Professional Services?

Comment: You would need to make the conversion call

Comment: Thanks @EazyE - so I can leverage SSJS and automation studio for both historical data and offline purchases?