# Einstein Recommendations - How to Import Offline or Historical Data Feeds?

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein, einstein-recommendations, behavioral-triggers

How does one go about importing an offline or historical data feed of purchases into Marketing Cloud?

Reading the documentation I know it can be done: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_pb_catalog_faq6.htm&type=5#mc_pb_integration_with_contact_builder

Reading other stackoverflow pages I see someone recommended making the conversion call: [Einstein Email Recommendations - historical purchase data](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/321511/einstein-email-recommendations-historical-purchase-data)

But the documentation says historical purchases should come through in a catalog format.  If so, where in the UI do I import historical purchases?

If I am supposed to do it via SSJS, is the process to convert every purchase to a Conversion Collect call as described on this page and then run it via an SSJS activity in automation studio?
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/pb-collect-tracking.htm

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct you simply need to make the call to record the conversion for the user/profile. There is a flag you want to use for these offline purchases `"special":"ownit"`

```
var url = 'https://'+MID+'.collect.igodigital.com/c2/'+MID+'/track_conversion?payload={"cart":[{"item":"'+itemID+'","unique_id":"'+SkuID+'","quantity":"'1'"}],"special":"ownit","user_info":{"email":"'+emailID+'"}}';
```